# Openpyxl missing 'jdcal'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I tried to install the `openpyxl` module, but during the installation it showed some errors with `JDcall`. When I then try to import it, I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Andrzej\workspace\sandbox\sandbox.py", line 7, in <module>
    import openpyxl 

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .workbook import *

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 35, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .worksheet import *

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 35, in <module>
    import openpyxl.cell

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\cell\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .cell import *

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 47, in <module>
    from openpyxl.date_time import (

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.0.5-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\date_time.py", line 34, in <module>
    from jdcal import (

ImportError: No module named 'jdcal'
```

I get this same problem for Python 3.4 and 3.3, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should install [jdcal](https://pypi.python.org/simple/jdcal/) separately. After this, install [Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I faced the same issue - after doing this, it got resolved

Comment: jdcal will be installed automatically. If this does not happen then something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After I downloaded the jdcal-x.x.x.tar.gz from https://pypi.org/project/jdcal/#files and extracted it in \path\to\pythonxx\Lib\site-packages\ I had to copy the jdcal.py file from \path\to\pythonxx\Lib\site-packages\jdcal-1.4.1\ to \path\to\pythonxx\Lib\site-packages\ in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

`jdcal` is a library required by openpyxl but should be installed automatically. How are you installing openpyxl?

Comment: Tried `easy_install openpyxl`, `pip install openpyxl` and even `python setup.py install` but all give same result.

Comment: Something is wrong if you can use `python setup.py`. What OS are you you on? Installing jdcal `pip install jdcal` should solve your problems.

Comment: Windows 7. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: have the same problem on OSX with macports (and macports seems not to know anything about `jdcal`)

Comment: @AndreHolzner then you should submit a bug to the port's maintainer. openpyxl is best installed using pip

Comment: How does "How are you installing openpyxl?" answer the question? I am none the wiser.

Comment: @Schorsch if the library is installed as described in the documentation then all dependencies will be installed automatically. Some people package the library up and neglect to make sure those dependencies are also installed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get **openpyxl** to work by uninstalling **openpyxl**, **jdcall** and **et-xmlfile**, then reinstalling all three, then upgrading all three.

Not sure why it works, and the error messages are still there, but I was able to successfully import **openpyxl** and create a workbook.