# Getting error while using OpenPyXL in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am not able to use `openpyxl` in python. I am getting the below error while compiling a simple python program.

```
from openpyxl.reader import excel
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import cell
from openpyxl import worksheet
wb = excel.load_workbook(filename = 'res.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
ws = wb.get_active_sheet
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\openpyexcel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl.reader import excel
  .....
    from jdcal import (
ImportError: No module named jdcal
```

While running setup.py for openpyxl, we are getting below error:

```
Processing dependencies for openpyxl==2.1.4
Searching for jdcal
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/jdcal/

Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for jdcal
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('jdcal')
```

Could you please help, where I am making error..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Openpyxl missing 'jdcal'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360450/openpyxl-missing-jdcal)

Answer (score -1):

The `jdcal` library is required to work with dates and is automatically installed if you install openpyxl correctly: `pip install openpyxl`.