# Openpyxl in Python is borked

Tags: python, macos, pip, openpyxl

I have looked and done my research. I have read/write permissions on my Library and I've updated pip. However, I cannot import openpyxl at all. This is the error I get:

```
 >>> import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "openpyxl/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "openpyxl/workbook/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "openpyxl/worksheet/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .worksheet import Worksheet
  File "openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 34, in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell
  File "openpyxl/cell/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell
  File "openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from openpyxl.utils.datetime  import (
  File "openpyxl/utils/datetime.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jdcal import (
ImportError: No module named jdcal
>>>
```

Comment: OK, just going out on a limb here, but do you have jdcal installed? I ask, because it sure looks like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360450/openpyxl-missing-jdcal

Comment: yep, that's what I had to do. I have pip, pip3, pip3.5, pip2, pip2.7 and its all really confusing. Thanks!

Comment: Great, you're welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl missing 'jdcal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360450/openpyxl-missing-jdcal)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have jdcal installed run

```
pip install jdcal
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I also had to install et_xmlfile.