# Openpyxl won't import

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Using Python 3.8.2 and have openpyxl 3.0.3 installed (by using "pip install openpyxl"

Trying to get the following code to work:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

When trying:

"import openpyxl"

I am getting  the error:

```
"C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/statsparser/venv/excelprocessor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/statsparser/venv/excelprocessor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook 
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 24, in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\cell\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 27, in <module>
    from openpyxl.styles import numbers, is_date_format
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\styles\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .alignment import Alignment
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openpyxl.descriptors import Bool, MinMax, Min, Alias, NoneSet
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\descriptors\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from openpyxl.utils.datetime import from_ISO8601
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\statsparser\venv\openpyxl\utils\datetime.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jdcal import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdcal'
```

Process finished with exit code 1"

When trying:

"from openpyxl import workbook"

getting same error.

"from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import worksheet"

getting same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openpyxl missing 'jdcal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360450/openpyxl-missing-jdcal)

Answer (score 1):

The essence lies in the statement: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdcal'`

Follow this answer to install `jdcal`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360450/openpyxl-missing-jdcal)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the error message to check whether module **jdcal** is installed.

1. `pip freeze` or `pip list` to check the installed package
2. If jdcal is not in the list, `pip intsall jdcal` would be the solution